# How to calculate minutes difference between two times

Tags: java

How to calculate difference between minutes of two times only, let's suppose we have two times (LocalTime in java).

- onDutyTime = 08:00
- offDutyTime = 14:30

to get hour's difference i used `onDutyTime.until(offDutyTime, ChronoUnit.HOURS)` which give me correct result of 6 hours. But how to get minutes difference (30) between these two times minutes.OR there is any other way so that i can get compete time difference 6:30.

Comment: I am not sure if the API has a better method, but `onDutyTime.until(offDutyTime, ChronoUnit.MINUTES) % 60` should work.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using `Duration`.

```
LocalTime onDutyTime = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
LocalTime offDutyTime = LocalTime.of(14, 30);

Duration d = Duration.between(onDutyTime, offDutyTime);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(d.toMinutes());
System.out.println(d.toHours());
System.out.println(d.toMinutesPart());
```

This outputs

```
PT6H30M
390
6
30
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64542028/1876620) for a better approach.

---

I would use:

```
long amount = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(start, end);
```

This returns the amount of minutes between two `LocalTime` instances.

You could also use:

```
long amount = onDutyTime.until(offDutyTime, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

Then, simply divide by `60` to obtain the hours:

```
long hours = amount / 60;
```

And get the remainder to obtain the minutes:

```
long minutes = amount % 60;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following operation:

```
LocalTime timeDiff = t2.minusNanos(t1.toNanoOfDay());
```

The result will contain all time units you want, without need to divide time amounts.